# Design issue in wrapping "C" API into OO wrapper

Tags: oop, design-patterns, architecture

I am trying to build an object oriented wrapper, which will wrap API specification; this includes a many structures, events, and APIs.
This API specification will be revised every year, there by releasing new specification; the updates are likely to have newer structures, events and APIs. Updates will also include
Updates to existing structures, events and APIs, the APIs as such does not change but as they take various structures as parameters which eventually have updates

The challenges

1. The API specification is nothing but an SDK to a lower layer,
   what I am trying to build is also an SDK but will be an object
   orient wrapper over this SDK.
2. The requirement is that  the users
   want Objects and methods and no “C” like structures and APIs
3. The frequent version change should not have any impact on high level
   application and should seamlessly work with any underlying API
   version
4. Older application should work on newer APIs
5. Newer application should work on older APIs

The last one is a tricky one, what I mean is that the newer application when it sees that it an older version of SDK should somehow transform itself to an older version of API

Is there any design pattern which will help me achieve this task and tied over the frequent changes to internal data and also achieve backward compatibility and forward compatibility?

OS: Windows
 Dev Environment : Visual C++

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is too high level to be answerable by a design pattern.
What you are asking for are architectural principles.

These you should base on your well-founded design decisions ("API is backwards compatible using versioning because...") which in turn are based on your requirements (e.g. "Older application should work on newer APIs").

Look into this (a presentation keynote about API design by Joshua Bloch):

[How to Design a Good API and Why it Matters](http://lcsd05.cs.tamu.edu/slides/keynote.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

**1)** All that comes to mind at the moment, if the sdk API involves manual resource allocation:

RAII, or ctor,dtor resource management: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization

**2-5)** Determine a function decomposition of the API you're building, that becomes expressible in terms of each version tier of the SDK API. Some details on semi-formal function decomposition here (towards the bottom):

http://jfeltz.com/posts/2015-08-30-cost-decreasing-software-architecture.html

You can then take the resulting function compositions and make them construct-able objects if you have to. Don't worry about the final object model until you have a working understanding of the function compositions involved. This is hard at first, but trust me, it is far more powerful than iterating through several possible object model designs.

For C++, you'll probably need to perform #define pre-processing against a scheme of versions for each upstream SDK API, unless your sdk encodes its version in a file somewhere, such that you can do dll loading instead (in which case, this may be Factory design pattern), but I suspect you already knew that.

Comment: your article is too complex for me to understand..thanks for looking into this

Comment: What is complex about functions? You use them everyday  :). Let me know if you have a specific question about the article, and I will be happy to answer it.